# How to understand collation of INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS in Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure-sql-database

I try to do this:

```
CREATE TABLE #SourceColumns (Id INT NOT NULL, Field VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT NOT NULL);

insert into #SourceColumns values (1, 'test')

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS join #SourceColumns on COLUMN_NAME = Field;
```

and I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.
```

I know how I can fix it, but I want to understand it first.

I wanted to do this:

```
SELECT c.name AS column_name, c.collation_name
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
WHERE t.name = 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'
```

to see the collation of the COLUMN_NAME but I get an empty result.

Comment: System tables inherit the collation of the database.

Comment: Then from where results the error?

Comment: As a note, I can't replicate your error with the above SQL. I can only replicate it if I **remove** `COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT`. I suspect your temporary table isn't in the collation you think it is. Perhaps you `CREATE`d it in the wrong collation initially?

Comment: If you run the following query, I guarantee you get different collations: `SELECT [name], collation_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set(N'select COLUMN_NAME, FIELD from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS CROSS JOIN #SourceColumns',NULL,NULL);`

Comment: yes, i have different collations, hence the error. But what i want to understand is why is this happening. Why I have two different collations SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS and
Latin1_General_CI_AS.

Comment: See my prior comments; specifically [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76464886/how-to-understand-collation-of-information-schema-columns-in-azure-sql-database?noredirect=1#comment134829897_76464886).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to retrieve information about the columns in a database table and join it with data stored in a temporary table for further analysis or processing.

you can try this.

```
CREATE  TABLE #DummyTable (Id INT  NOT  NULL, Field VARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE  DATABASE_DEFAULT  NOT  NULL);
INSERT  INTO #DummyTable VALUES (1, 'example1')
SELECT c.name  AS column_name, c.collation_name
FROM tempdb.sys.columns c
JOIN tempdb.sys.objects o ON c.object_id  = o.object_id
WHERE o.name  LIKE  '#DummyTable%'
```

[image]